# On Same Button-Click, Div fadeOut and fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fadein, fadeout

i would like to create a one-page website where on click of the button the impressum-div will fade in. Another Click on the same button would then fadeOut the impressum-div.

I already managed it to fadeIn the div on click.
But when I try to use "if" the whole thing doesn't work anymore.
I already found some tipps here and tried them all but nothing really worked for me..

Here my Script-Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         function display() {

             if (document.getElementById("impressum").style=="none") {
                 $('#impressum').fadeIn();
             }
             if (document.getElementById("impressum").style=="block") {
                 $('#impressum').fadeOut();
             }
         }
     });
</script>
```

I tried this in several versions (with .click() and so on..), so this is probably totally wrong.

Here my HTML-Code:

```
<input type="button" id="iButton" value="Impressum" onclick="javascript:display()"/> 

       <div id="impressum" style="display:none">

       <p>Here Impressum</p></div>
```

Help is very much appreciated, if you could post a complete Function it would bethe best because i am only putting parts wildly together..

Greetings

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147788/jquery-click-btn-fade-in-out

Answer (score 5):

Just use fadeToggle()

```
<input type="button" id="iButton" value="Impressum" onclick="javascript:display()" />
<div id="impressum" style="display:none">
    <p>Here Impressum</p>
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#iButton').click(function () {
        $('#impressum').stop(true).fadeToggle();
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xZzN7/)

Comment: OMG Your My Hero, this totally Works!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="impressum" style="display:none">
    <p>Here Impressum</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#iButton').click(function () {
    $('#impressum').stop(true).fadeToggle();
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xKpLe/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve the `display` value like that, you need to use **[window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.getComputedStyle)**:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("impressum"),
    display = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("display");
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a4E6L/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
/* 1: <div onclick="display(this);"></div>*/
var display = function(elm){
  var status = G(elm).attrib('data-display')||'false';

    if(status=='false'){ 
        G(elm).css({display:'block'});
        G(elm).attrib('data-display', 'true');
        return false;}

    if(status=='true'){ 
        G(elm).css({display:'none'});
        G(elm).attrib('data-display', 'false');
        return false;}

    };



    /* 2 */
    /* elm.onclick = display;*/
var display = function(ev){
    var elm = this||G(ev).source(); //Choice
    var status = G(elm).attrib('data-display')||'false';

    if(status=='false'){ 
        G(elm).css({display:'block'});
        G(elm).attrib('data-display', 'true');
        return false;}

    if(status=='true'){ 
        G(elm).css({display:'none'});
        G(elm).attrib('data-display', 'false');
        return false;}

    };
```